# How do I tell if the frontmost window is a NSOpenPanel / file open dialog in MacOS using Applescript?

Tags: macos, applescript, nsopenpanel

I'm trying to automatically change the directory of the frontmost "file open dialog" or  NSOpenPanel dialog with AppleScript, whether that window is part of any application. The idea is that I hit a hotkey, and it will control that dialog to switch to a particular folder.

I can't seem to find out how to find the attributes of a window that would filter it for a "file open dialog". Using the Accessibility Inspector I can find that the "class" is `NSOpenPanel`. How can I get the class of a window using Applescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run the following AppleScript, you can see the properties of the foremost window:

```
tell application "anApp" to activate
delay 1
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "anApp"
        properties of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

The app has to be active to see the properties of the windows; You will not get consistent results if the app is in the background.

The NOOpenPanel ought to be recognizable by testing for some combination of the following properties:

- role description:"dialog"
- title:"Open"
- subrole:"AXDialog"
- name:"Open"
- description:"dialog"

Personally, I'd probably rely on `name` and `role description`, which should be the same anytime an app throughs up a standard 'Open' dialog. 'Save' dialogs will be the same, except that `title` and `name` will be 'save' rather than 'open'.

If you have an app that presents a open or save sheet (a sub window attached to the titlebar), not a separate dialog, then you'll shift things a little. The AppleScript to get the properties looks like this:

```
tell application "anApp" to activate
delay 1
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "anApp"
        tell window 1
            properties of sheet 1
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

and the relevant testable properties are as follows:

- accessibility description:"save"
- role description:"sheet"
- role:"AXSheet"
- description:"save"

You'll probably have to add logic to test whether the front window has a sheet, which should distinguish between dialogs and sheets.

Some apps use non-standard open/save dialogs, and you'll have to account for them on a case-by-case basis. There's no magic bullet for that.

Comment: RE: "The app has to be active to see the properties of the windows" -- That is not necessarily true.

Comment: @user3439894: On the apps I tested (Safari and BBEdit), the first showed no windows at all when it was in the background, and the second showed its main window but not the Open dialog. That may not be the case for all apps, but it is the case for some, so if consistent results are needed, the target app should have focus.

Comment: _"The app has to be active to see the properties of the windows; You will not get consistent results if the app is in the background."_. Even if this _can_ be true, the first assertion is false, to declare that **must** be in the foreground to retrieve properties.  Until today, reading your comment Re: Safari/BBEdit, I have never once had the issue arise for me, even for _Safari_.  I'm not suggesting you didn't get this issue; I would say, on balance, the strength of the original assertion could be dialled back from being an absolute truth to _"maybe-sometimes"_, or _"rarely, if ever"_.

Comment: @CJK: I have two concrete examples vs your general, non-specific experience. Possibly this is something new to Catalina (I don't remember this being the case previously, either), but it's a bit hard to argue with explicit facts. Find me three apps that this is *not* true for, and I'll consider making the grammar changes you're suggesting.

Comment: In most circles, the generalised form of anything is considered of greater quality than a few specifics (also referred to as "exceptions"). I stated that I have never had the issue with _any_ application, thus I believe I provided many more than the arbitrary three you seek. Nonetheless, [here's some properties for every window of every (window'd) application currently running on my machine](https://i.imgur.com/wkxbdLw.png).  You'll note _Safari_ is in there, and _not_ in the foreground. Q.E.D.